# Selenium. How open chrom with profile2?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

WHY IT DOESN`T WORK?

```js
String userProfile= "C:/Users/Leonid/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User
Data/Profile 2" ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir="+userProfile);
options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); WebDriver driver = new
ChromeDriver(options); driver.get("http:/www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible problems that come to mind are:

1. You have a space after "Profile" in your userProfile string
2. You're missing a forward slash in your google URL string

Comment: that's not the problem

Comment: Would need more context and a description of the expected behavior

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;